# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I installed the PubSub dependency in my project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I implemented a `TopicChannel` and `SubscriptionChannel`:

```
  @Configuration
@Slf4j

public class SubscriberChannel {
    private final String subscription = "test-sub";
    @Autowired
    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RfidReaderRepository rfidReaderRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BagDetectionRepository bagDetectionRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PersonDetectionRepository personDetectionRepository;


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageReceiver() {
        return message -> {

            String payload = (String) message.getPayload();
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            log.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + payload);

            BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage originalMessage =
                    message.getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE, BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage.class);
            originalMessage.ack();

         
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
                new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, subscription);
        adapter.setErrorChannelName("pubsubErrors");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);

        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubErrors")
    public void pubsubErrorHandler(Message<MessagingException> exceptionMessage) {
        BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage originalMessage =
                (BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage) exceptionMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage()
                        .getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE);

        originalMessage.nack();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "pubsubInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "100"))
    public MessageSource<Object> pubsubAdapter(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubMessageSource messageSource = new PubSubMessageSource(pubSubTemplate, subscription);
        messageSource.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        messageSource.setPayloadType(String.class);
        messageSource.setBlockOnPull(true);
        messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(20 * 1024 * 1024);
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

The topic channel

```
@Configuration
    public class TopicChannel {
        private final String topic = "testt";
    
        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
        public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
            return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, topic);
        }
    
        @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
        public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {
            void sendToPubsub(String text);
        }
    
    }
```

When  run the app I get this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'messageChannelAdapter' defined in class
> path resource
> [com/payfree/bftConfiguration/pubsub/SubscriberChannel.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'messageChannelAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path
> resource
> [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' defined in
> class path resource
> [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'defaultPublisherFactory' defined in class
> path resource
> [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.PublisherFactory]:
> Factory method 'defaultPublisherFactory' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't
> be null or empty.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you try that subscription format: `projects/<projectID>/subscriptions/test-sub` instead of `test-sub`? (replace `<projectID>` by your project ID)

Comment: Do you have any other spring-cloud-gcp dependencies on the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the projectId using gcloud-cli

```
gcloud config set project <your-project-id>
```

reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set

Install gcloud-cli if not already on your system. Link: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install